# Opencv : How to find least used color in an image

Tags: opencv

What could be the algorithm to find the least used color in an image? I am new to opencv.

My code after reading responses.
How can I improve it? Also how can I check if it is working for 'least used color'.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Load the file
char* filename = argv[1];
cv::Mat matImage = cv::imread(filename);

if(!matImage.data) {
    printf("Unable to open the file: %s\n", filename);
    return 1;
}
const int width = matImage.cols;
const int height = matImage.rows;
printf("\n height -> %d , width -> %d\n",height,width);
map<string,int> mymap;
int c = 1;
for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {
    cv::Vec3b* ptr = matImage.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(y);
    for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {
        cv::Vec3b color = ptr[x];
        char buff[16];
        sprintf(buff,"#%02x%02x%02x",color[0],color[1],color[2]);
        string s(buff); 
        if(mymap.find(s) == mymap.end()){
            mymap[s] = 1;
        }
        else 
            mymap[s] = mymap[s] + 1;
    }
}
cout<<"color count = "<<mymap.size()<<endl;
int max = 0;
int min = mymap.size(); 
string strmax,strmin;
for (std::map<string,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it){
        if(it->second > max)
        {
            max = it->second;
            strmax = it->first;
        }
        if(it->second < min)
        {
            min = it->second;
            strmin = it->first;
        }
    }
    cout<<"most used color -> "<<strmax<<" count -> "<<max<<endl;
    cout<<"least used color -> "<<strmin<<" count -> "<<min<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe in more detail what problem are you trying to solve. What kind of images do you have, how do you define color? And, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Some colours might not be present all. Are they least used?

Comment: I guess you could make a 16 million entry array indexed by (R<<16)|(G<<8)||B and then pass over all the pixels incrementing the corresponding entry then find the minimum, non-zero entry in that array. It would probably only take around 64MB of RAM or so which is nothing on multi GB computers.

Comment: Your code looks pretty sensible. You can check the frequency of occurrence of colours using **ImageMagick** which is available on most Linux distros and for macOS and Windows. Use this command in the Terminal `convert YourImage.png -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format %c histogram:info:-`

Comment: I put all the advice together as an answer so folks don't have to scrabble around through comments.

Answer (score 0):

The primary colors of Red,Green and Blue present in the image can be easily detected by the following process in openCV.

```
split((Image),channels);  
Mat red, blue, green;

inRange(channels[0], Scalar(50), Scalar(255), blue); // blue
inRange(channels[1], Scalar(50), Scalar(255), green); // green
inRange(channels[2], Scalar(50), Scalar(255), red); // red

double image_size = abs((Image).cols * (Image).rows);  // Total no of pixels in the image
double red_percent = ((double) cv::countNonZero(red))/image_size;
double blue_percent = ((double) cv::countNonZero(green))/image_size;
double green_percent = ((double) cv::countNonZero(blue))/image_size;
```

Comment: The question is how to find the least used color. How does you response answer that?

Comment: Any color is formed by these combination only, if percentage of red is minimum then red related color(pink,orange etc) in the image is least used.

Comment: The question is about the least used color (e.g. #fcbb33) and not just the primary color. How does knowing red is the least used primary help in finding the real least used color (dark red, light red, brick red)?

Comment: But how would I find the least used color (exact color, asked in the above comment). For example to find the most used or dominant color we can use k-means algorithm. What algorithm we can use to find least used color?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make a 16 million entry array indexed by `(R<<16)||(G<<8)||B` and then pass over all the pixels in the image incrementing the corresponding entry. Then make a pass over the array to find the minimum, non-zero entry in that array.

It would probably only take around 64MB of RAM or so which is nothing on multi GB computers.

**Updated since your added your code**

Your code looks pretty sensible. As a check, you can get the frequency of occurrence of colours using **ImageMagick** which is available on most Linux distros and for macOS and Windows.

Use this command in the Terminal to see the 10 least frequently occurring colours:

```
convert YourImage.png -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format %c histogram:info:- | sort -n | head -10
```

**Sample Output**

```
    35: (104, 89,206) #6859CE srgb(104,89,206)
    39: (109, 83, 47) #6D532F srgb(109,83,47)
    51: (103, 73,135) #674987 srgb(103,73,135)
    59: (214,120,103) #D67867 srgb(214,120,103)
    59: (223,224,228) #DFE0E4 srgb(223,224,228)
    63: (202,115,117) #CA7375 srgb(202,115,117)
    67: (205,150, 72) #CD9648 srgb(205,150,72)
    71: (230,164, 96) #E6A460 srgb(230,164,96)
    75: (173,149, 83) #AD9553 srgb(173,149,83)
    77: (182,134, 55) #B68637 srgb(182,134,55)
```

So that means that colour #6859CE is the least frequently occurring colour in my sample image at 35 pixels total count.

---

If you install **ImageMagick** v7+, that command will become:

```
magick YourImage.png -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format %c histogram:info:- | sort -n | head -10
```